# 2 ethernet ports, one on 100mbps, one on 1000mbps problem?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, ethernet, ifconfig

I ran across a strange sight when I ran ifconfig first time today.  I have a gigabit server card with 2 ports.  I have it set in a bond for 802.3ad usage as my switch supports it.  It appears though that one port is at 100mbps and one is at 1000mbps.  Any good reason for this?

Is there any fix to get both connections at 1000mbps???

Answer (score 0):

Hi check the cabling as 1000Mbps generally needs cat6 Ethernet. my network dropped to 100 and it turned out the problem was a piece of cat5 between a pc and the switch: got 5m of cat6 back to 1000Mbps networking.

Comment: trust me, my whole network is cat6 :)  I ended up removing the bond all together and just using port 2 and i'm getting 1Gbps now